# Create a cumulative array with float

Tags: java, android, arraylist, mpandroidchart

I need to get cumulative values of a sequence of negative and positive float values and put in an [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) entry:

```
private ArrayList<Entry> chartValues;

public void getTransactions() {
        (...)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objInfo = info.getJSONObject(i);

                    (...)

                    int transaction_type = objInfo.getInt("transaction_type");
                    float transaction_amount;
                    if(transaction_type == 0){
                        transaction_amount = -(float) objInfo.getDouble("transaction_amount");
                    }else{
                        transaction_amount = (float) objInfo.getDouble("transaction_amount");

                    }

                    chartValues.add(new Entry(i, transaction_amount));

                }
        (...)
}

private void setData(int count, float range) {

    LineDataSet set1;

    if (chart.getData() != null &&
            chart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (LineDataSet) chart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(chartValues);
        chart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
    (...)
}
```

`chartValues` returns {1.00, 2.00, -3.00, 4.00, 5.00 ...} and I need to return {1.00, 3.00, 0.00, 4.00, 9.00}. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly you need? Sort the entries by the lowest value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need additional variable to keep total sum of items:

```
public void getTransactions() {
        (...)
                float sum = 0.0f;
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objInfo = info.getJSONObject(i);
...
```

And use it:

```
              sum += transaction_amount;
              chartValues.add(new Entry(i, sum));

                }
        (...)
}
```